# How can I block an ip to a redirect php file?

Tags: php, datetime, redirect, time, ip

This is my redirect file in php

```
<?php
header("Location: https://www.example.org/advertisement.php");
?>
```

What code do I need so that when a person with an ip. For example, 192.168.1.1 can only be redirected once a day or once per hour to that file `advertisement.php`, and when you try it a second time in a certain time. For example, send it to `https: // wwww.example.org/only-one-visit-per-hour-is-allowed.php` or print a message saying: You have visited this website recently, return in 1 hour.

Comment: You would need to keep a list of IPs and check that list with each page load. What have you tried?

Comment: save the IP and time to a file\db ... or course IP != user; so its basically a pointless idea

Comment: If you don't mind that the user can get around it, you can use a cookie to keep the time when they first accessed on a day.

Comment: Using a cookie is a bad idea. Cookies are clientside and can easily manipulated by the client. So no security at all

Comment: as if IP is any better @Lithilion

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to manually enter the ips of the users, I would like a code that, when a user opens that php, save your ip and the time in the db and then redirect it to for example, ad1.php and if the user re-open the php file in less than an hour or same day. print a message that says: You visited this ad a short time ago. or if not, send it to another php file that prints the message.

Comment: @LuisCesar we understand that, but what are you asking us for help with? what have you tried and failed? can you get the user IP, can you write to a db\file ...help us help you :-)